# Codeigniter email problems

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am trying to send an email using codeigniters email library, this is my code,

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize(array('mailtype' => 'html'));
$this->email->from('emailaddresshidden'); // TODO - Store this in Config file??
$this->email->bcc('emailaddresshidden');
$this->email->subject('Competition Entry'); // TODO - What does this want to be??
$this->email->message($this->load->view('emails/competition_entry', $this->data, TRUE));
$this->email->send();
```

However I am getting this error,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail() expects parameter 1 to
>   be string, array given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1519

I have no idea as to why?

Comment: Can you show the method that contains line 1519?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a `to`, not just `bcc`s

Comment: I don't understand it: in https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/c9f9ca0fdb0c/system/libraries/Email.php#cl-67 it seems the first param IS an array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/c9f9ca0fdb0c/system/libraries/Email.php#cl-257 it is important to use the method `to()` as @Pekka said. Else the the first parameter will not be transformed into a string.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention $this->email->to('receiver@email.com'); Then this error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/201596/ all you gotta do is add a call to `$this->email->to('')` with a blank string as the first parameter.

```
$this->email->to("");
$this->email->bcc($emails);
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

$this->email->to(' ');
Just insert this line above the bcc() line.